# Can a resource be made available offline by using cache-control HTTP headers?

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, offline-caching

I'm aware of HTML5 app cache, which can be used for creating offline applications through the use of a cache manifest file.

Is there a way to make the browser load a resource offline (from cache when the Internet is disconnected) using just standard HTTP headers? If so, what headers should I be sending?

Comment: how did you solved your problem ?

Comment: @KunalBalani: You can't do this using just HTTP headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible through the use of standard HTTP caching headers.